Chart js 2.9.4 - showing tooltip of another column in bar chart
I am using Angular 4 and Chart js 2.9.4 - bar chart and pie chart where I am hovering on 2nd column and showing me tooltip of 1st column.I have tried different configuration in tooltips using position, mode and debugged the code in the chart 2.9.4 library as well but, still I am not able to figure out.

type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [X,Y,Z],
                datasets: [{
                    label: [''],
                    data: [
                        10,
                        12,
                        14
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'red'
                        'yellow',
                        'blue'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                layout: {
                    padding: {
                        left: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        top: 0,
                        bottom: 0
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [
                        {
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                display: false,
                            },
                            gridLines: {
                                display: true,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                    xAxes: [
                        {
                            gridLines: {
                                display: true,
                            },
                        },
                    ],
                },
                legend: {
                    display: false,
                },
                tooltips: {
                    position: 'average',
                    intersect: false,
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                            const dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                            const value = dataset.data[tooltipItem.index];
                            const label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
                            return `${label}: ${value}`;
                        }
                    }
                },
                onClick: function (event) {
                    const activePoints = this.getElementsAtEventForMode(event, 'nearest', { intersect: true }, true);
                    if (activePoints.length) {
                        const firstPoint = activePoints[0];
                        const label = this.chart.data.labels[firstPoint._index];
                        const value = this.chart.data.datasets[firstPoint._datasetIndex].data[firstPoint._index];
                        console.log(`Clicked on ${label}: ${value}`);
                    }
                }
            }


Can't reproduce from the posted code, fiddle. Might be an angular-related issue.

what angular related issue? I am using angular 4.1.3 version.

Hello Rishabh, I can't know what the issue could be; I just made the observation that without the angular part, in chart.js on vanilla JS the issue doesn't manifest itself. Maybe, since you already isolated/posted the most relevant part of your code, you could wrap it in some of the angular stuff in a codesandbox or stackblitz such that we get the error to appear.

In this fiddle, I changed height from 90vh to 900px, this issue will reproduce.




This is my html code
Hi Rishabh, I finally managed to reproduce your issue. I created an easier to reproduce fiddle if you come with the mouse pointer from bellow the x axis up to either of the three bars - the tooltip will always appear over the middle (yellow) bar.

The explanation of this behavior is that chart.js compares the cartesian distances between the mouse pointer and the center of each bar, and the nearest center might not be the one of the bar over which the pointer is. Everything fits, except the picture you posted, in which the pointer appears to be closer to the yellow center than to the red one. In any case, if the explanation is right the solution would be to add mode: 'x' to the tooltips configuration. Could you please test it and let me know, so I could post a more complete explanation if it works, or look further into it otherwise
